# Separar consulta en columnas sql

Tags: sql-server, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente resultado:

```
Zona    sucursal    da1 da2 da3 cant
0004    007         A   B   C   100
0004    007         B   B   C   200
0004    007         C   B   C   100
0004    007         D   B   C   200
0004    007         F   B   C   200
0004    006         G   B   C   200
0004    006         H   B   C   220
0004    006         Q   B   C   200
0004    006         F   B   C   100
0004    006         F   B   C   100
```

lo que quiero hacer es que como tengo en sucursal 5 datos iguales 007 y 005 quiero que no me presente asi la infotmacion quiero que la columna cant se pase aun lado de esa manera.

```
Zona    sucursal    dato 1  dato 2  dato 3  cantidad    Zona    sucursal    dato 1  dato 2  dato 3  cantidad
0004    007     A   B   C   100                          0004   006 G   B   C   200
0004    007     B   B   C   200                          0004   006 H   B   C   220
0004    007     C   B   C   100                          0004   006 Q   B   C   200
0004    007     D   B   C   200                          0004   006 F   B   C   100
0004    007     F   B   C   200                          0004   006 F   B   C   100
```

como ven la sucursal es el mismo dato pero quiero dividirlo a otra columna tengo la query de la siguente manera:

```
SELECT ZONA.CLAVE AS ZONA, ZONA.CLAVE AS SUCURSAL, DETALLE.DAT1, DETALLE.DAT2, DETALLE.DAT3, DETALLE.CANT FROM ZONA AS ZONAS
LEFT JOIN DETALLE ON DETALLE.SUCURSAL= ZONAS.ZONA.CLAVE
```

Comment: En gereral los problemas de vista (como este) los debe resolver la vista. Un query seria ultra complejo y generaria montones de joins para tratar de entender como generar cada fila. piensa que la DB ejecuta las instrucciones fila por fila, entonces para lo que queres deberias generar multiples consultas y luego unirlas.

Comment: Usar pivot podría ser buena práctica ?

Comment: No se como usarias pivot en este caso.

Comment: Añade DDL y así es más fácil que alguien te pueda ayudar.

Comment: ¿Solo tienes 2 sucursales? ¿Que pasa si tuvieras 3 por ejemplo?